# Почему код не считывает отрицательные числа из файла

Tags: python

Входной файл содержит:

8

7

-100

a

Вывод только [8, 7]
Как исправить? Не понимаю

```
f_in = open('input.in', 'r')
f_out = open('output.out', 'w')

Lines = f_in.read()
my_set = set ()
s = list(my_set)
results = list(map(int, s))
with open('input.in', 'r') as f:
   my_list = f.read().splitlines()
   for elem in my_list:
       if elem.isdigit():
           results.append(elem)
print(results)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[str.isdigit](https://pythonz.net/references/named/str.isdigit/) возвращает True, только если строка состоит только из цифр.

Попробуйте так (взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279732/how-to-type-negative-number-with-isdigit)):

```py
   for elem in my_list:
       try:
           int(elem)
           results.append(elem)
       except ValueError:
           pass
```

или так (но это вернёт True для строки '------1'):

```py
   for elem in my_list:
       if elem.lstrip("-").isdigit():
           results.append(elem)
```